# Clear connections to SharePoint in Word Document

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, ms-office

We are having issues with word connecting to SharePoint to retrieve data even if we've downloaded a document from the site.

Here is how our process is setup

1. We work with documents and prepare them on the workspace
2. When done a publishing workflow copies the documents using `SPFileCollection.Add(string urlOfFile, byte[] file, bool overwrite)`, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms428630.aspx

[image: The process]

The issue is when opening documents either directly from the published documents site collection or even if we download them to disk the word goes to the workspace site to fetch data (Word Phone Home).

[image: Fiddler]

This issue is related with the post linked below but I want to break the "phone home" behavior.

- https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19390/what-is-slowing-the-opening-of-office-documents

Comment: One thing any Word document will be linked to is its template. Unless the template location is fixed up by the publishing workflow, a .docx will still have a relationship in settings.xml.rels that points to a template in the Workspace. Could be worth looking at that and fixing the .docx.

Comment: @bibadia Yeah I figured that it is the template url that links the document to sharepoint even if we didn't set it. Next stop will be to learn how to clear that value during the copy.

Comment: Probably Open XML SDK and look specifically for that relationship. Although there may be other relationship types you could also check for easily, my guess is that if the user could conceivably link to any kind of external binary object, you are unlikely to be able to pick up everything.

Comment: @bibadia, Gee, I was hoping for a property in the SPFile object :)

Comment: :-) search me, guv! (Not familiar enough with the SP SDK stuff, sorry).